# Download Images from google drive using API in node.js

Tags: google-drive-api

```js
Hi @iansedano, I wanted the code for achieving this. Below is my code : 

// [START drive_quickstart]
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
const readline = require('readline');
const {google} = require('googleapis');

// If modifying these scopes, delete token.json.
const SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive'];
// The file token.json stores the user's access and refresh tokens, and is
// created automatically when the authorization flow completes for the first
// time.
const TOKEN_PATH = 'token.json';

// Load client secrets from a local file.

let credPath = path.join(__dirname,'../../credentials.json');
fs.readFile(credPath, (err, content) => {
    if (err) return console.log('Error loading client secret file:', err);
    // Authorize a client with credentials, then call the Google Drive API.
    authorize(JSON.parse(content), getFiles);
});

/**
 * Create an OAuth2 client with the given credentials, and then execute the
 * given callback function.
 * @param {Object} credentials The authorization client credentials.
 * @param {function} callback The callback to call with the authorized client.
 */
function authorize(credentials) {
    const {client_secret, client_id, redirect_uris} = credentials.installed;
    const oAuth2Client = new google.auth.OAuth2(
        client_id, client_secret, redirect_uris[0]);

    // Check if we have previously stored a token.
    fs.readFile(TOKEN_PATH, (err, token) => {
        if (err) return getAccessToken(oAuth2Client, callback);
        oAuth2Client.setCredentials(JSON.parse(token));
    });
}

/**
 * Get and store new token after prompting for user authorization, and then
 * execute the given callback with the authorized OAuth2 client.
 * @param {google.auth.OAuth2} oAuth2Client The OAuth2 client to get token for.
 * @param {getEventsCallback} callback The callback for the authorized client.
 */
function getAccessToken(oAuth2Client, callback) {
    const authUrl = oAuth2Client.generateAuthUrl({
        access_type: 'offline',
        scope: SCOPES,
    });
    console.log('Authorize this app by visiting this url:', authUrl);
    const rl = readline.createInterface({
        input: process.stdin,
        output: process.stdout,
    });
    rl.question('Enter the code from that page here: ', (code) => {
        rl.close();
        oAuth2Client.getToken(code, (err, token) => {
            if (err) return console.error('Error retrieving access token', err);
            oAuth2Client.setCredentials(token);
            // Store the token to disk for later program executions
            fs.writeFile(TOKEN_PATH, JSON.stringify(token), (err) => {
                if (err) return console.error(err);
                console.log('Token stored to', TOKEN_PATH);
            });
            callback(oAuth2Client);
        });
    });
}

/**
 * Lists the names and IDs of up to 10 files.
 * @param {google.auth.OAuth2} auth An authorized OAuth2 client.
 * @param fileId
 * @param fileName
 */

    function getFiles(auth) {
        const drive = google.drive({version: 'v3', auth});
        var filePath = path.join(__dirname, './../../images/photo.png');
        //var filePath = path.join(__dirname,'./images/'+fileName+'.png');
        var dest = fs.createWriteStream(filePath);
        drive.files.get({fileId: '1hEKDGM4OoLQhhpSpqSxaMkrz0WmByQ0B', alt: 'media'}, {responseType: 'stream'},
            function (err, res) {
                res.data
                    .on('end', () => {
                        console.log('Done');
                    })
                    .on('error', err => {
                        console.log('Error', err);
                    })
                    .pipe(dest);
            }
        );
    }
// [END drive_quickstart]

module.exports = {
    SCOPES,
    getFiles,
};
```

`Can any one help me download the file from Google drive using API in node.js ?

I have enabled the Google Drive API and created credentials.json from the oAuth2.

I need the code to download the image file using the file id. Please note that there is no web application involved here and I'm creating a Test script using codeceptjs to download the image from google drive and upload in another application.

Comment: Are these threads useful for your situation? [Ref](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=%5bgoogle-drive-api%5d%20%5bnode.js%5d%20download)

Comment: Can you share your code?

Comment: @iansedano Added the code here. I now want to know I can use the API key alone to get the image downloaded from Google drive ?

Comment: What is the issue with the code so far? Are you getting any error messages? Did you manage to get the quickstart to work following the instructions on the reference docs?